# What is better one SVG sprite or Separated SVG icons or PNG sprite?

Tags: html, svg, sprite

I have many SVG icons for navigation menu.
I don't know what is best practice to get SVG icons in my web page.

[image]

what is the best and why ?

1- Use SVG Icons directly  => is this need more http request to get svg from server ?

2- Convert SVG icons to one SVG sprite => is this bad performance ?

3- Convert SVG icons to one PNG Image sprite ?

Comment: You should mention what requirements you have. Without objective goals, this question is primarily opinion based. As an example, converting SVGs to PNGs can be useful, if you need to support 10 year old browsers. Stuff like that. So what conditions are you working with?

Comment: I work in modern browsers , I want to know best practice